# HDInsight Storage not found in multiple subscription

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to run Azure HDInsight Cluster from PowerShell and getting error while getting storage key from my azure account :

```
Get-AzureSubscription -Default

$subid = (Get-AzureSubscription -Current).SubscriptionId
$clustername = "bigdatajs1"
$storagename = "bigdatajs1"
$containername = "bigdatajs1"

$creds = Get-Credential

#get storage for key
$key1 = (Get-AzureStorageKey $storagename).Primary
```

PS C:\Users\milind.chavan> $key1 = (Get-AzureStorageKey $storagename).Primary
Get-AzureStorageKey : ResourceNotFound: The storage account 'bigdatajs1' was not found.

Comment: What do you want help with? The error looks quite self explanatory to me

Comment: I had two subscriptions, I had to change my subscription to get default one.

Answer (score 0):

By changing the subscription I can manage to get ride of this issue

Comment: If you're going to answer your own question, can you at least post the code that will **a)** allow you to list subscriptions **b)** select a subscription other than the default